# New error getting Azure file list from shared folder

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-files

I'm trying to read a file from shared file from an Azure function.
All works fine in local, but I'm getting "shareName" error when I deploy my project.
The code is very simply:

```
 string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyStorage", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        string FileSharedContainer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MySharedContainer", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        string InputCloudFolder = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("InputCloudFolder", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        string ProcessedCloudFolder = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProcessedCloudFolder", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        CloudFileClient cloudFileClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
        CloudFileShare cloudFileShare = cloudFileClient.GetShareReference(FileSharedContainer);
        CloudFileDirectory rootDirectory = cloudFileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
        CloudFileDirectory InputfileDirectory = rootDirectory.GetDirectoryReference(InputCloudFolder);
        CloudFileDirectory ProcessedfileDirectory = rootDirectory.GetDirectoryReference(ProcessedCloudFolder);
        List<IListFileItem> fileList = GetAllFilesFromDirectory(InputfileDirectory);
        string fileNames = "";
        foreach (var p in fileList)
        {
            var CurrentFile = (CloudFile)p;
            fileNames += CurrentFile.Name +" ";
        }
        return new OkObjectResult("N. File processed is: " + fileList.Count + ".  Filenames" + fileNames);
```

It's a demo http trigger function that returns a file list from a shared files folder even on Azure.
It works perfectly on local machine but it fails on deploy environment with this error:

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'shareName')

I never heard this parameter!!!

Please help me....!

Comment: Have you specified “MySharedContainer” environment variable in your deployed environment? What is the value of that?

Comment: Yes. It’s a string stored into local.settings.json file with the name of the file share’s storage account under which I’ve defined my subdirs and files.